# Typeorm respository find where with select columns

Tags: sql, node.js, typeorm

I am trying to implement single query with a where clause and select columns:

Main Query  in SQL form:

```
SELECT name from users WHERE flag = 1;
```

Now what I have tried so far is:

```
userRepository.find({
    where: {
        flag: 1
    },
    select: {
        name: true
    }
})
```

My query works fine if I don't add `select` option, but with select provided it gives me error.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select like this

```
userRepository.find({
where: {
    flag: 1
},
select: ['name','id']
```

})